# using gets.chomp twice in a one line call to a nested hashmap - ruby

Tags: ruby, hashmap, chomp

what is the best way of using gets.chop for the following example?

```
user = {}
user["list"] = [ {gets.chomp => {gets.chomp.delete(' ') => rand(1000000000000)} } ]
```

I can think of:

```
a = gets.chop ; b = a.delete(' ') ; user["list"] = [ {a => {b => rand(1000000000000)} } ]
```

but perhaps there is a better way?

any ideas? Can I do it without creating the vars a & b ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to set a variable to use the input in two different places. ALthough it can be compacted into the following :

`user["list"] = [ {a=gets.chomp => {a.delete(' ') => rand(1000000000000)} } ]`

Comment: For some reason I was thinking that if I used `a=gets.chomp` inside the dictionary, the value of `gets.chomp` would not be saved... but no, this works... I just wish there was a way to do this without using a variable.

Comment: If you could input it when you run the script from command line (`ruby myscript.rb input`) you could then access the input this way : `user["list"] = [ {ARG[0].chomp => {ARG.shift.chomp.delete(' ') => rand(1000000000000)} } ]`

Comment: interesting! I will have a play with that. I was thinking of having something like `.storevariable` so `gets.chomp.storevariable` is saved as `storevariable` which can then be edited...